# How can I get IE 11 to stop reverting to Start with tabs from last session?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

I'm using Windows 7 Pro (32 bit) with Internet Explorer 11. My preference is to have IE start with my home page.

[image]

A few times a week, it changes itself to `Start with tabs from last session`.

[image]

After I reset it to `Start with home page` and save the settings, it will change it back sometime later. This does not appear to be event or time specific.

There are no error messages or prompts. The computer is clean of viruses and malware. There are no redirects or hijack issues with IE or other browsers.

My profile is administrator and there are no group policies involved. I have searched here and various other technical sites with little results.

How can I stop Internet Explorer from changing this setting?

Comment: IE11 has some serious problems with sessions it seems, see my question about the reverse situation, where my saved sessions are simply lost because IE11 even after I close it continues to have a ghost process running in the background.

Comment: Is that the only setting reverting back or are others doing this too?

Comment: That is the only one changing.

Comment: How do you shut down the computer (if you do)? Do you close everythihg first, hit the shutdown button, hard shut down etc?

Comment: The computer is left on during the week. When needed, use `Start > Shutdown` to turn the PC off. Browser windows are closed normally with the **X** in the corner before locking or shutting down.

Comment: To me, it sounds/seems like IE is going kaboom some where when closing, and when you re-open it's thinking it shut down incorrectly and trying to restore how it was! In fact,When I RDP into my work PC, I do it via IE using a Java (yuk) plug in. This in turn runs a process called Cisco Scanner and every so often, it will shutdown all my browsers (for unknown reasons). When I start IE, it will ALWAYS try to restore my last tabs without a prompt

Comment: When that happens, does it actually change the IE settings to the "Start with tabs from the last session"?

Comment: I would need to check that... Sorry, I may have gotten excited hoping I had a possible solution ... :S

Comment: I am familiar with what you are talking about because I have seen it on other PCs (I have other PCs with the same setup). None of the others do what this question is about.

Comment: Is this a domain-joined computer, or a standalone box? And have you tried making the change to the user's registry directly at HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ContinuousBrowsing, value name "Enabled", REG_DWORD  = 0 for Home Page, 1 for last session tabs. It almost sounds like something is affecting the user profile. Also check your event logs for failures to unload current user profiles..

Comment: What antivirus / anti-malware software do you use?

Comment: @Steven We use Trend Micro Security on all of our PCs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the most direct way using GPEDIT.MSC

Run gpedit.msc
Navigate to :
User Configuration=>Administrative Templates=>Windows Components=>Internet Explorer =>Internet Control Panel =>General Page In right window you have 
"Start Internet Explorer with tabs from last browsing session"
Double click it and Disable the setting.

Just as a precaution, always better to have IE closed when making GP changes, not all the time but it seems to apply better for me. I would post a screenshot but I'm a noob apparently

Comment: Great! That was it. I had looked through all those setting in `gpedit`, but missed that one. With the award of the bounty, you are no longer a noob. :)

Comment: Glad it worked for you mate :)

Comment: Changing this setting from Not Configured to Enabled worked to fix an issue I was having where "Start with tabs" was selected but it was having no effect.  Thanks